# Datatypes in Java and their representation

Tags: java, types, primitive-types

I have question about primitive types in Java (`int`, `double`, `long`, etc).

Question one:

Is there a way in Java to have a datatype, lets say `XType` (Lossless type) that can hold any of the primitive types?
Example of hypothetical usage:

```
int x = 10;
double y = 9.5;
XType newTypeX = x;
XType newTypeY = y;

int m = newTypeX;
```

Question two:

Is there away to tell from the bits if this number (primitive type) is an integer, or a double, or a float, etc?

Comment: Do you mean [the Numbers classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) which are wrappers for Java primitives? [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) is the super type for all number wrappers, so because of auto-boxing, replacing `XType` with `Number` should work ok.

Comment: Question two is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891595/check-type-of-primitive-field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) class, which is the super class for all [numeric primitive wrapper classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html), in your first snippet:

```
int x = 10;
double y = 9.5;
Number newTypeX = x;
Number newTypeY = y;
```

The conversion between the primitive types (`int`, `double`) and the object type (`Number`) is possible through a feature called [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). However, this line won't compile:

```
int m = newTypeX;
```

because you cannot assign the super type variable into an `int`. The compiler doesn't know the exact type of `newTypeX` here (even if it was assigned with an `int` value earlier); for all it cares, the variable could as well be a `double`.

For getting the runtime type of the `Number` variable, you can e.g. use the [`getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method:

```
System.out.println(newTypeX.getClass());
System.out.println(newTypeY.getClass());
```

When used with the example snippet, this will print out

```
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Double
```

Comment: Autoboxing came with Java 5.0, before you would have to write `Number x = new Integer(10);` To get the type you can use `instanceof`, but it will become an ugly `if`. Overloading methods might be better than using `Number` depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
Integer i = 1;
Float f = 2f;
Object[] obArr = new Object[]{i, f};
Float fReconstruct = (Float) obArr[2]
```

Not really primitive types, but the closest you can get!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your first question, for those you can use the [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) class.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Object to hold reference to any of these types, but it will be 'boxed' to it's wrapper (int will be hold as an Integer, long as a Long, etc.)...

Answer (score 0):

Not yet (java 8), and not in the way you want to get the primitive value back. But if instead of holding a primitive type you hold a primitive type wrapper (which are classes that descend from the `Object` class and wrap their corresponding primitive, i.e. `Byte` wraps `byte`, `Integer` wraps `int`, `Long` wraps `long`, etc), then you could do this:

```
public class Holder<T extends Number> {

    private final T number;

    public Holder(T number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public T get() {
        return this.number;
    }
}
```

You could use this `Holder` class to hold an instance of any subclass of `Number`, **including primitive types wrappers**. For example:

```
Holder<Integer> holderX = new Holder<>(5);
Holder<Double> holderY = new Holder<>(1.234);

int x = holderX.get(); // 5
double y = holderY.get(); // 1.234
```

The above is possible because of a feature of Java called [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), along with another feature called [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

[Extending generics to support primitive types](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/218) is being considered for Java 9 or 10 (not sure), under the term *Specialization*. In theory, this would allow you to have:

```
List<int> list = new ArrayList<int>();
```

[Here is a draft](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/valhalla/specialization.html).

Answer (score -1):

**Generics** are a facility of generic programming that were added to the Java programming language in 2004 within J2SE 5.0. They allow "a type or method to operate on objects of various types while providing compile-time type safety.

For an example I like the one on tutorialspoint:

```
public class GenericMethodTest
{
   // generic method printArray                         
   public static < E > void printArray( E[] inputArray )
   {
      // Display array elements              
         for ( E element : inputArray ){        
            System.out.printf( "%s ", element );
         }
         System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        // Create arrays of Integer, Double and Character
        Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Double[] doubleArray = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
        Character[] charArray = { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O' };

        System.out.println( "Array integerArray contains:" );
        printArray( intArray  ); // pass an Integer array

        System.out.println( "\nArray doubleArray contains:" );
        printArray( doubleArray ); // pass a Double array

        System.out.println( "\nArray characterArray contains:" );
        printArray( charArray ); // pass a Character array
    } 
}
```

This would produce the following result:

```
Array integerArray contains:
1 2 3 4 5 6

Array doubleArray contains:
1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 

Array characterArray contains:
H E L L O    Array integerArray contains:
1 2 3 4 5 6

Array doubleArray contains:
1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 

Array characterArray contains:
H E L L O
```

For more on [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm).